# Error while printing the address of array elements in C

Tags: c

I have an error message:

> cannot increment value of type int[2]

Is that because the size of `int` or what?

```
int arr[2]={10,20};
printf("%p \t %p \t",arr,++arr);
```

Comment: you can't iincrease every elment cause the `++` operator uses `int` not `int[2]`. its cause you can't increment arrays

Comment: so is the only way to get the address of arr[1] is: printf("%p",arr[1]) );

Comment: or there's another way to access the address!

Comment: Use `printf("%p \t %p \t",(void *) arr, (void *) &arr[1]);`

Comment: It's _undefined behaviour_ anyway. Read a C bokk about the basics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please note that you are trying to modify address of array.

Consider:

```
printf("%p \t %p \t",arr,++arr);
```

I think you want to print the address of the array element at 2nd position(index 1).

To print the address if `arr[1]` you can try:

- &a[1]
- (a+1)
- use pointers
- use dynamically allocated arrays

  ```
  #define ARRAY_COUNT 10
  int main() {
      int *arr = (int*)malloc(ARRAY_COUNT*sizeof(int));

      while(*arr != 0) {
          printf("%p ",arr);
          arr++;                  
      }
      return 0;
  }
  ```

**Final Code:**

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int arr[2]={10,20};
    int *ptr=arr;
    printf("%p \t %p \t\n",ptr,ptr+1);
    printf("%p \t %p \t\n",arr,arr+1);
    printf("%p \t %p \t\n",arr,&arr[1]);
    return 0;
}
```

**Sample Output:**

```
sh-4.3$ gcc -o main *.c
sh-4.3$ main
0x7fffdf064110   0x7fffdf064114
0x7fffdf064110   0x7fffdf064114
0x7fffdf064110   0x7fffdf064114
```

---

Also note that the statement:

```
printf("%p \t %p \t",arr,++arr);
```

is an **Unspecified** or **Implementation-specific** behavior since it can (and does) produce different results on different machines. To be concise, the order(left to right or otherwise) of passing the arguments to functions is not strictly specified by `C`.

Here:

```
printf("%p \t %p \t",arr,++arr);
```

- **Case 1:** Left to right parameter passing causes `arr` address(address of a[0]) to be printed first and then incremented to print the next address(address of a[1])

  Output:

  ```
  0x7fffdf064110   0x7fffdf064114
  0x7fffdf064110   0x7fffdf064114
  0x7fffdf064110   0x7fffdf064114
  ```
- **Case 2:** Right to left parameter passing causes `arr` address to be incremented first and printed (address of a[1]) and then print the address(address of a[1])

  Output:

  ```
  0x7fffdf064114   0x7fffdf064114
  0x7fffdf064114   0x7fffdf064114
  0x7fffdf064114   0x7fffdf064114
  ```

Answer (score 1):

The only reason you are **not** able to modify its value is once you define a *static* `array` with `n` size then a ***variable name*** given to it is treated as constant pointer *(Whose value can't be changed)*.

> This restriction is imposed by the compiler because it thinks if you change the value `arr` then there no way to ensure the accuracy of the program because the base address has been modified

But if you really want to play with the pointers then check these codes:

```
int main() {
    int arr[] = {1,2,3,0};
    int *ptr = arr;

    while(*ptr != 0) {
        printf("%i ",*ptr);
        ptr++;                   // or     ++ptr;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**Output:** 1 2 3

```
int main() {
    int *arr = (int*)malloc(4*sizeof(int));
    arr[0] = 1;   
    arr[1] = 2; 
    arr[2] = 3; 
    arr[3] = 0;

    while(*arr != 0) {
        printf("%i ",*arr);
        arr++;                  
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**Output:** 1 2 3

I hope i made myself clear. Any doubt most welcome.